# Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" with blank value

Tags: java, json, number-formatting

I get ther error when `JSON` string have some blank value, getting from server,
how to deal with blank values
 here is JSON

```
{  
   "status":"success",
   "data":[  
      {  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"ABC",
         "address":"ABC, QWE",
         "lat":"16.799999",
         "lng":"96.150002",
         "admin_id":"4",
         "is_approved":"1",
         "added":"2015-08-07 11:17:12",
         "status":"1",
         "image_file":"",
         "image_width":"",
         "image_height":""
      }
   ]
}

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyData>>() {}.getType();
myDataArrayList = gson.fromJson(response.getString("data"), listType);
```

In MyData class I tried to change `lat, long` type `int` and changed value in json also for the same but still showing same error

```
public class MyData implements Parcelable {

    public int id;

    public String name;

    public String address;

    public String lat;

    public String lng;

    public String added;

    public int status;

    public String image_file;

    public int image_width;

    public int image_height;

}
```

Showing error in this line

```
myDataArrayList = gson.fromJson(response.getString("data"), listType);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of image_width and image_height to String in MyData Class

```
public String image_width;

public String image_height;
```

As int will not be able to store "" this string, and at the time of using it you can parse it into int.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int image_width;     // Expected integer value while parsing 

public int image_height;   // Expected integer value while parsing
```

as you can see below you are having string fields . Initialize below vale to 0

```
"image_width":0,
"image_height":0
```

Comment: Thanx @Gokul ,I fixed it with another way, to initialize `image_width` and `image_height` to 0` I have to make changes on server side